# Textarea with brackets not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery

This script is used to comment to a post. I can't figure out how to make - `textarea name='send[mc_comment]` from the form work.

When text is added to send[mc_comment] it works, but only on the first or second comment and the other comments are empty!

a, b, c, d, e work as they should. Can anyone help me with this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var commentUrl = "comments.php";
function mainComment(a,b,c,d,e,f) {
    var f = $("textarea[name=send[mc_comment]]").val();
    var page = (d);
    $("#"+page).text("Please wait...").show();
    $.post(commentUrl,{user:a, friend:b, postid:c, where:d, which:e, send:f},function(data){$("#"+page).html(data).show().fadeOut(1000)})
}
</script>
```

The form contains:

```
textarea name='send[mc_comment]'

a href='#' onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:mainComment('php echo $usercode; ', 'echo $othermember;', 'echo $curpost;', 'echo 'add'.$curpost;', '<echo $comment;');">Yes /a
```

comments.php

```
<?php
$send = $_POST['send'];  
$user = $_POST['user'];  
$friend = $_POST['friend'];  
$postid = $_POST['postid'];  
$where = $_POST['where'];  
$which = $_POST['which'];

if($which == 'comment'){
    print_r($_POST).'<br />';
    echo "a ".$user." b ".$friend." c ".$postid." d ".$where." e ".$which." f ".$send."<br />";
}
?>
```

print_r display from comments.php:

```
Array ( [user] => 9uVrPykP5u [friend] => 9uVrPykP5u [postid] => 41 [where] => add41 [which] => comment [send] => Some text added to the form. )
```

This only works on the first post comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("textarea[name='send[mc_comment]']").val();
```

Comment: I have 10 posts and if the comments start with the first comment to the last, your code works.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't finish. It only works in sequence. If I comment on 2 thru 10 it does not work.